# How to display an element using `ng-if` and dynamically update the value from outside the app?

Tags: angularjs

I have a notifications panel. I need to display it only if there are errors. So, I set attribute in my controller called errors :

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $mdToast, $templateCache, $animate, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $log) {
    var mainCtrl = this;

    mainCtrl.errors = false;
```

So in the notifications element I can use like this :

```
ng-if="mainCtrl.errors"
```

Initially this is hidden. But after we submit the form (I use Rails for the backend) Rails will send a javascript file and it will run. I need to update the value of `error` and add content to the element dynamically on that seperate js file. How can I do this?

Comment: if you have errors, then why would you allow the form to be submitted? for that matter, if they are errors on the client, wouldn't they be errors in Rails as well?

Comment: "add content to the element" - are you trying to show the returned error messages?

Comment: Whats in the js file returned by your rails server?

Comment: @Claies Im new to angular and learning step by step. So for now im not going to use angular validations. Im submitting the form and then rails will send the error messages is there are any. I can get the errors using the returned js file

Comment: @vonv. Yes im trying to show the returned errors

Comment: @timsmiths The js file is empty. I can add anything I want in there. I can get the errors to that js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller -

```
 .controller('mainController', function($scope, $mdToast, $templateCache, $animate, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $log) {

$scope.errors = false;
```

In your view -

```
ng-if="mainCtrl.errors"
```

In your js file -

```
angular.element($0).scope().errors = true;
```

Note : Make sure js file runs in context of your page.

Comment: Can you share your value of angular.element($0).scope() ?

Comment: Found the answer! Just have to call `scope().$apply();` to apply the changes! :-) Thanks!